# Changing the back ground color of list item on selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

HI I want to change the background color of my menu item which ever is selected I have tried 
following function but is not working

```
$('#list-menu a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
```

but I am getting no Where Thanks 
here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zahid_nisar/LJKvm/) link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS was slightly off.

You had a stray comma in

```
#list-menu a.active {
 border: 1px solid #000000;
background: #333333;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

I also switched out the JQ although I'm no expert

```
$('#list-menu a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#list-menu a').not(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LJKvm/19/)

As for your original JQ, I believe it's because you were applying the change to the anchors which have no siblings inside the `li`

Answer (score 0):

You could first remove all classes and then add the class you want:

```
$('#list-menu a').click(function(){   
    $('#list-menu a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Your `.siblings()` selector doesn't work because the link is actually nested inside a `li`, therefore there are no more `a` you can target inside the `li`. I suggest you move the .active class from the `a` to the `li`, in this way you can change the background of the active item in this way:

```
$('#list-menu li a').click(function(){   
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/grMGJ/)